# Make the measure constant - Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, measure

I want to use 24.80%(measure) for my calculations in below table(visual). But I want this to be remains constant and not update with first column. Is there a way this can be achieved?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this measure:

```
Chat Containment = "24.80%"
```

[image]

Comment: Did this solve your problem?

Comment: No, REMOVEFILTERS(PLV_Type4) did the job for me.

Comment: Yup, you should definitely think about deleting this question. Or at least rename it to "How to use REMOVEFILTERS on a mearsure.... to remove filters from a measure"